# Rename componentWillReceiveProps to componentDidUpdate

Tags: react-native

I'm following this tutorial, to build an expandable listview:

https://medium.com/@iakash1195/expandable-listview-in-react-native-53ebdd78abea

It works, but I'm receiving a warning saying that:

> Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not
> recommended for use. See
> fb.me/react-unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.
>
> - Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
> - If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static
>   getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at:
> - Rename componentWillReceiveProps to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the
>   UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their
>   new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in
>   your project source folder.

I tried to rename componentWillReceiveProps to componentDidUpdate, but the expandable listview stopped working

I could just run the command to rename the deprecated functions, but this solution is far from being the best.

> npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles --force

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the warning suggests, `componentWillReceiveProps` has been deprecated and you should use `static getDerivedStateFromProps` instead.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if  (nextProps.item.isExpanded && prevState.layoutHeight) 
    return {
      layoutHeight: null
    };
  return {
    layoutHeight: 0
  };
}
```

You can read more about this lifecycle method at [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

Answer (score 0):

You should not longer use componentWillReceiveProps. The new and more efficient Solution to get props changes is with the function getDerivedStateFromProps

Read this:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops